# Pixi.js makes browser crashed when use PIXI ticker

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

My problem is chrome browser stopped after about 2 minutes later ticker started.

```js
const renderer = new PIXI.Renderer({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0x2c3e50,
    antialias: true,
});

const stage = new PIXI.Container();
const ticker = new PIXI.Ticker();

const initialLine = new PIXI.Graphics();
const dx = 0.2;

const xData = [50, 100, 150, 200];
const yData = [20, 90, 40, 100];

let lastX = xData[xData.length - 1];
let lastY = yData[yData.length - 1];


document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

const simpleLine = () => {
    initialLine.lineStyle(2, 0xFFFFFF, 1);
    initialLine.moveTo(0, 0);
    for (let i = 0; i < xData.length; i++) {
        initialLine.lineTo(xData[i], yData[i]);
    }

    initialLine.position.x = 150;
    initialLine.position.y = 50;

    stage.addChild(initialLine);
}

const addLine = () => {
    const lastIndex = xData.length - 1;
    const newX = xData[lastIndex];
    const newY = yData[lastIndex];

    initialLine.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    initialLine.lineTo(newX, newY);
}

const moveLine = () => {
    initialLine.position.x -= dx;
}

const setTicker = () => {
    ticker.add(() => {
        moveLine();
        addLine();
        renderer.render(stage);
    }, PIXI.UPDATE_PRIORITY.LOW);
    ticker.start();
}

const changeData = () => {
    lastX = xData[xData.length - 1];
    lastY = yData[yData.length - 1];
    xData.push(lastX + 10);
    yData.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}

setInterval(() => {
    changeData();
}, 1000);

simpleLine();
setTicker();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.0.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

It's a simple code for a line chart.

1. Add a basic PIXI container
2. Draw the first line with 4 dots.
3. Add next line every second using PIXI ticker and Change line x position.

It works nicely at the moment But about 2 minutes later, the browser is crashed.

I don't know why and how can I fix it.
Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an out-of-memory error. Potentially a memory leak. If run with the dev tools open, it says "Paused before potential out-of-memory-crash".

The memory usage quickly surpasses 1500 MB. But if these lines are commented out, the memory usage seems to remain stable:

```
// xData.push(lastX + 10);
// yData.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
```

However, when the out-of-memory error occurs, `xData.length` is about 90. These arrays cannot be taking up the 1500+ MB.

I am not sure how PIXI stores graphics objects, but I think `initialLine` is consuming most of the memory. That `initialLine` is being moved to the left, and there is a large, growing portion that cannot be seen. An out-of-memory error is inevitable! Ideally, the parts of `initialLine` that are not visible should be freed.

The [PIXI.graphics API](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html) doesn't seem to have a way to free old line segments. Instead of continuously moving and adding more line segments, I would [clear](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#clear) the previous graphics and redraw the entire line (skipping parts of the line that are not visible).

Comment: Thanks. It's super helpful to me. Then I knew what I have to do.
but one more question, many people in pixi community told that use PIXI.RednerTexture for optimization. But it seems to be used with PIXI.Sprite.

so, do I have to use PIXI.RenderTexture with PIXI.Graphics? or is it ok to use just PIXI.Container?

Comment: @DylanJu: I'm not sure.. Try to figure it out yourself (it might just "work"), then ask a new question on StackOverflow~

Comment: @DylanJu: That's great! Congrats